# How to implement Native Ads without MediaView

Tags: android, admob, ads, native-ads

I want to implement Native Ads in RecyclerView without MediaView, So referred to [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed-android/#0) after following this I successfully implemented native ads in RecyclerView but my need is to load only icon, heading, advertiser and call to action button not the MediaView, etc.

So I removed the MediView and other elements Code from the implementation which I made after which the code looks like this

UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder.java

```
package com.mishracodes.myapplication;

import android.view.View;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView;
public class UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private UnifiedNativeAdView adView;
    public UnifiedNativeAdView getAdView() {
        return adView;
    }
    UnifiedNativeAdViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        adView = view.findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
        adView.setHeadlineView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_headline));
        adView.setCallToActionView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_call_to_action));
        adView.setIconView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_icon));
        adView.setAdvertiserView(adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_advertiser));
    }
}
```

and inside the RecyclerViewAdapter.java the part of code which manages NativeAdView

```
private void populateNativeAdView(UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd,
                                      UnifiedNativeAdView adView) {
        ((TextView) adView.getHeadlineView()).setText(nativeAd.getHeadline());
        ((Button) adView.getCallToActionView()).setText(nativeAd.getCallToAction());
        NativeAd.Image icon = nativeAd.getIcon();

        if (icon == null) {
            adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((ImageView) adView.getIconView()).setImageDrawable(icon.getDrawable());
            adView.getIconView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (nativeAd.getAdvertiser() == null) {
            adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            ((TextView) adView.getAdvertiserView()).setText(nativeAd.getAdvertiser());
            adView.getAdvertiserView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd);
    }
```

loading Native Ad function in MainActivity.java

```
    private void loadNativeAds() {

        AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(this, getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
        adLoader = builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(
                new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                        mNativeAds.add(unifiedNativeAd);
                        if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                            insertAdsInMenuItems();
                        }
                    }
                }).withAdListener(
                new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "The previous native ad failed to load. Attempting to"
                                + " load another.");
                        if (!adLoader.isLoading()) {
                            insertAdsInMenuItems();
                        }
                    }
                }).build();
        adLoader.loadAds(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), NUMBER_OF_ADS);
    }
```

Now after doing this I used Native Ad Validator to validate if the ads are implemented correctly
Result:
[image]

But After testing it for sometime I got this error
[image]

Warning in detail
[image]

So Is there any way to Call for Loading Native Ad so that only those ads are called which do not have Media View. As I have Seen Many Apps which uses native ads like this without Media View.
[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how did you use this AdMob native ads validator because I searched a lot I couldn't find it so please tell me how do you do that because I also want to validate my ad

Comment: @TECHSMASH add this  **<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.flag.NATIVE_AD_DEBUGGER_ENABLED"
            android:value="true" />** inside application tag in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks, But its not working can you explain?

Comment: @mishracodes can you please explain what should I do to validate native ads... its not enough to add meta data with NATIVE_AD_DEBUGGER_ENABLED... Documentation is so poor about this. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can but it was possible before as Google made it mandatory to add `MediaView`. Also it's a good idea as your revenue would be increased but it may affect the user experience. Finally, you can't do this because if you upload it to the play store then Google will send you a warning notice saying that you didn't add `MediaView`. It may affect your earnings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm too late, but it helps someone. I found a way to implement native ads without that MediaView.

The logic is Google has provided [some native templates](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-native-templates). These are for beginners who want to get started with native ads without implementing them from scratch. There are two templates - gnt_small_template_view and gnt_medium_template_view. gnt_small_template_view doesn't have MediaView. You can happily implement it in recycler view and also you can change the layout as per your requirement (but don't change the view ids). The original layout doesn't look good. You mostly change it.

[Here is the documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/templates).

I have added these templates to my app, I didn't face any issue.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer for this particular question.